# JavaScript Regular Expressions Special Characters

Tags: javascript, regex

Why does this regular expression

```
/^[^-_]*([A-Za-z0-9]{3,})+[-_]?[^-_]*$/i
```

match on this String?

```
,abc,,.
```

It clearly says that the String should only contain of

1. Minimum 3 letters
2. Followed by an optional - or _
3. Sequence of number 1 and 2 can be repeated infinite times
4. No - or _ at the beginning or end of the String

The regex should not allow any other characters than `A-z`, `0-9` and `- or _`, but yet, it allows them.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `^[^-_]*` means: a string starting from any character except `-` and `_` repeated 0 or more times.

Comment: Your steps (1-4) are basically inaccurate to fully describe the regex.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Erm, actually, it clearly says:

- From the start,
- Any number of characters that are not `-` or `_` (matches `,`)
- *Catastrophically backtrack* to find at least three alphanumerics (matches `abc`)
- Optionally match a `-` or `_` (matches nothing)
- Any number of characters that are not `-` or `_` (matches `,,.`)
- To the end.

Did you mean:

```
/^[a-z0-9]{3,}(?:[-_][12]+)?$/i
```

Correction, I misunderstood your "point 3".

```
/^[a-z0-9]{3,}(?:[-_][a-z0-9]{3,})*$/i
```

Comment: Thank you. I had a look on google but didn't find what '?:' means. Could you explain that to me? Thanks in advance

Comment: Non-capturing subpattern.

Answer (score 1):

`[^-_]*` means 0 ore more characters that are not `-` or `_`, `,` and `,,.` satisfies that condition.

Answer (score 1):

`[^-_]*` will match the first comma, `([A-Za-z0-9]{3,})+` will match the `abc`, `[-_]?` will not match anything, `[^-_]*` will match the last 2 commas and the dot.

Note that using the `i` flag allows you to use `([A-Z0-9]{3,})+` or `([a-z0-9]{3,})+` just as well as your current regex.

---

If you want:

1. Minimum 3 letters
2. Followed by an optional - or _
3. Sequence of number 1 and 2 can be repeated infinite times
4. No - or _ at the beginning or end of the String

Then I would suggest:

```
/^(?:[a-z]{2}[-_]?)+[a-z]$/i
```

If by 'letters' you actually wanted letters and numbers, then I would suggest:

```
/^(?:[a-z0-9]{2}[-_]?)+[a-z0-9]$/i
```

Answer (score 1):

```
[^-_]*
```

is not "no - or _" but is "*everything* else than - or _"
as every other part of your expression may be absent...

```
[^-_]*
```

make your Regexp matching the string.